# Extract And capture Elements in a string using RegEx, and determining using a conditional if the regex will work for a given string

Tags: regex, if-statement, go, conditional-statements

While Developing in Go, How Would one Given a string extract certain elements between "%" and then capture the substring to the right of the last "%" as one element? How would one Also Check if the Regex operation can be performed to the given string?

```
Ex: 
This is %StackoverFlow% and it's a %Phenomenal%  "$ resource
$ presentations and got credit for it. I brought this up to  $
$ were She looked at me and said. She looked at me and said, $
```

Now I'd Like to get

```
element 1: StackoverFlow

element 2: Phenomenal

element 3:  "$ resource
$ presentations and got credit for it. I brought this up to  $
$ were She looked at me and said. She looked at me and said, $
```

What I've Accomplished to do So far, this expression will capture the two elements inside "%"

```
\%(.*?)\%
```

But I can't figure out how to proceed to capturing everything to the right of the element as a single capture within the same Regex Expression?

#2) How can we create a conditional to determine the String contains a substring with %content%?
E.g.

```
This is StackOverFlow
```

This String does not contain "%" with content between it, is there a way the we can determine if the regex will work on this string above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following pattern seems to be working:

```
%(.*?)%[^%]*%(.*?)%\s+(.*)
```

### Demo

Explanation:

```
%(.*?)%      match and capture first term %...% in $1
[^%]*        consume all content up until hitting the next
%(.*?)%      %...% term in $2
\s+          match one or more whitespace characters
(.*)         match and capture the remaining content in $3
```

Note that I am using dot all mode for this regex.  If you do not have dot all mode available, then use `([\s\S]*)` for the final component of the above regex pattern.